# How can I setup TypoScript in TYPO3 6.2.11?

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.2.11 and I have created the extension using the Extension builder extension then I want to setup TypoScript so the **TypoScript object selector** extension can detect it.

after googling the problem I come out with the following solution so the setup.txt file content as following but I still can not select my extension actions from the **TypoScript object selector** extension.

generated setup.txt file

```
plugin.tx_hr {
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_hr.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_hr.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_hr.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_hr.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    features {
        # uncomment the following line to enable the new Property Mapper.
        # rewrittenPropertyMapper = 1
    }
}

plugin.tx_hr._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE (
    textarea.f3-form-error {
        background-color:#FF9F9F;
        border: 1px #FF0000 solid;
    }

    input.f3-form-error {
        background-color:#FF9F9F;
        border: 1px #FF0000 solid;
    }

    .tx-hr table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border-spacing:10px;
    }

    .tx-hr table th {
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .tx-hr table td {
        vertical-align:top;
    }

    .typo3-messages .message-error {
        color:red;
    }

    .typo3-messages .message-ok {
        color:green;
    }

)
```

I have added the following code at the end of the setup.txt file

```
lib.tx_hr = USER
    lib.tx_hr = 10
       10 { 
            userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
            pluginName = Jobs
            extensionName = Hr
            controller = Job
            vendorName = MyCompanyName
            action = list
            switchableControllerActions {
              Job { 
                1 = list
              }
            }

            settings =< plugin.tx_hr.settings
            persistence =< plugin.tx_hr.persistence
            view =< plugin.tx_hr.view
            update =< plugin.tx_hr.update

      }

    page = PAGE
    page.10.variables.jobsWidget < lib.tx_hr
```

any help?

Comment: Did you __include static from extension__ within your main TS template?

Comment: I did but I still can not select my extension actions from the TypoScript object selector extension

I have added the following object and it appears normally.

jobsObject = TEXT
jobsObject.value = <strong>Some HTML code</strong>

then this object appears and I can select it.

Comment: why my extension actions does not appears?